# Boundedness of integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions, integral-inequality

I am currently working on a research project and have kind of stuck in proving the boundedness of a certain integral of a continuously differentiable signal $f(t)$. I have managed to prove the following properties:

1. **$f(t)$ is uniformly bounded.**
2. **$\frac{1}{t}\int_0^t{sf^2(s)}ds$ is uniformly bounded.**

From 2. it is easy to prove that
$$\inf_{\tau\in[0,t]}|f(\tau)|\leq \sqrt{\frac{2\sigma}{t}}\qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad(1)$$
for some $\sigma>0$.

From the simulations I run it seems that the whole function has a behavior of the form
$$|f(t)|\leq \sqrt{\frac{\eta}{t}}\qquad\qquad \qquad\qquad\qquad\quad(2)$$
for some $\eta>0$ but I could not prove that.

So my question is this:

**Do these properties 1., 2. suffice to prove that $\int_0^t{f^4(\tau)d\tau}$ is uniformly bounded or do I need to impose some extra assumption?**

Note that from (2) the boundeness of $\int_0^t{f^4(\tau)d\tau}$ follows directly.

Note also that I cannot use boundedness of $f'(t)$ since, in my current setting, this property follows as a consequence of the boundedness of the integral $\int_0^t{f^4(\tau)d\tau}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to impose some further assumptions. I will ignore the differentiability and give a merely continuous example for simplicity, but it should be clear that mollification to obtain a smooth function doesn't alter the overall behaviour.

Let $g$ be a piecewise linear function, such that it has a symmetric triangular spike of height $C > 0$ and width $\frac{2}{n}$ on the interval $[n - 1/n, n + 1/n]$ for $n \geqslant 2$, and let it be $0$ elsewhere. Let $f(\tau) = \sqrt{g(\tau)}$. Then $f$ is continuous, and uniformly bounded - $0 \leqslant f(\tau) \leqslant \sqrt{C}$ for all $\tau$ - and we have

$$\int_{n - 1/n}^{n + 1/n} sf(s)^2\,ds = n\int_{n-1/n}^{n+1/n} g(s)\,ds = n\cdot \frac{C}{2}\cdot \frac{2}{n} = C$$

for $n \geqslant 2$. It follows that

$$\lim_{t\to \infty} \frac{1}{t} \int_0^t s f(s)^2\,ds = C.$$

But, for $n \geqslant 2$ we have

$$\int_{n-1/n}^{n+1/n} f(\tau)^4\,d\tau = 2\int_0^{1/n} (Cns)^2\,ds = \frac{2C^2}{3n},$$

whence

$$\int_0^t f(\tau)^4\,d\tau \sim \frac{2C^2}{3}\log t.$$

Comment: Thank you Daniel for your answer! In my case, $f(t)$ is a state of a dynamical system with zero equilibrium, so we cannot have $f(T)=0$ for some time $T$ since then we have $f(t)=0$ for all $t\geq T$. However, my insight suggests that a similar proof can be also found in this case $f(t)\neq 0$. So, assuming that $f(t)\neq 0$ do you think that if we also assume a bounded upper derivative of $f^2(t)$ for certain time intervals of nonzero measure will suffice to prove the desired result?

Comment: If we add something strictly positive and quickly decaying, nothing essential changes. I very much expect that such a phenomenon like in the answer is ruled out by physical constraints and you actually have good behaviour, but I can't say what additional conditions do that. I'm not sure what a "bounded upper derivative … for certain time intervals" means, but you don't need much more than you have, condition 2 implies that $\lvert f(\tau)\rvert$ is small on average for large $\tau$, and already weak constraints on the derivative ensure that $\lvert f(\tau)\rvert \to 0$ in a not-too-slow way.